# How can I store edited text file using bash?

Tags: bash, zenity, kdialog

This is my code:

Edit_Record() {

```
zenity --width=600 --height=300 --text-info --title="Records" --filename=$FILE --editable
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
            kdialog --title "Saving the Data" --warningyesnocancel "Do you want to save the changes?"
            if  [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
            kdialog --msgbox "The changes have been added!"

            Home;

            elif [ "$?" = 1 ]; then
            kdialog --msgbox "No changes has been added!"
            Home;

            else
            Home;

            fi;

    else

    zenity --info --text "You chose to Cancel."
    exit
    fi;
}
```

I dont know what to put behind "kdialog --msgbox "The changes have been added!" :(
Help please?

Comment: Mixing zenity and kdialog? Why?

Comment: just wanted to experience the different gui's in one programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zenity --editable` returns the edited text to standard output. You can save it to a temporary file by redirection, and if the user wants to save the changes, just move the temporary file over the original.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
zenity --editable ... > $tmp

if ... ; then
    mv $FILE "$FILE"~
    mv $tmp "$FILE"
fi
```